# how to get home years from sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to produce the result:

```
Table: HWData
Effective Date:        Year Built:    Home Age:     Home Age Factor:
10/8/2011               1980           31              1.1
```

From the rules below:

```
New Construction        0.800
1 to 5 years old        0.850
6 to 10 years old       0.900
11 to 15 years old      0.950
16 to 20 years old      1.000
21 to 30 years old      1.050
31 to 40 years old      1.100
over 40 years old       1.150
```

This is what I have:

```
Select HWData.[Effective Date],
   HWData.[Year Built],
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM [Effective Date]) - HWData.[Year Built] AS Home Age, 
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] = 0, 0.8,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] <= 5, 0.85,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] <= 10, 0.9,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] <= 15, 0.95,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] <= 20, 1,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] <= 30, 1.05,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] <= 40, 1.1,
   iif(HWData.[Home Age] > 40, 1.15,
   0)))))))) AS [Home Age Factor]
FROM HWData 
INNER JOIN Factor_HomeAge
   ON HWData.[Policy Number] = Factor_HomeAge.[Policy Number]
```

But the whole sql codes just would not run. Is there a direct way to obtain the home years?

I think the inner join is also wrong since there is no column name Factor_HomeAge.[Policy Number].

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` will be wrong without `Factor_HomeAge.[Policy Number]` existing.  What columns are available in the `Factor_HomeAge` table to Join on?  Can you post the table structure of your tables?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM [Effective Date])` Access has a `DATEPART` function.  You will want to use:

`DATEPART("YYYY", [Effective Date])`

I also noticed your first `IIF()` statement: `iif(HWData.[Home Age] = 0, 0.8,`

If you allow partial year values for the house age, you may want to change the query to:

`iif(HWData.[Home Age] < 1, 0.8,` to account for homes that are less than one year old.